# Cant reach on completion listener for the second time, android studio

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

We are working on an app where we play 3 songs from an array List. After the first song, the next should be played after pressing play again (This is working). But after the second song finished we want a Start Game button to come up. We implemented this in an OnCompletion method, this is working for the first song but not for the second one.
This is a part of the code:

```
@Override public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {

            //adding the start game button after song finishes for the first time
           // Button start_button = findViewById(R.id.startGame);
           // start_button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            Button start_button = findViewById(R.id.startGame);
            start_button.setText(getString(R.string.START));
            start_button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            //changing the play button to replay after song finishes
            ImageButton imgButton = findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
            imgButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.replay);

        }

    });

public void NextSong(View view) {

    // Logic following
    if (songs.size() == 3) {
        songs.get(0).stop();
        songs.get(0).release();
        mediaPlayer.release();
       mediaPlayer=null;
        //songs.get(0).reset();
        songs.remove(0);
        Button NextSong = findViewById(R.id.NextSong);
        NextSong.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        final TextView result_display = findViewById(R.id.result_view);
        result_display.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else if (songs.size() == 2) {
        songs.get(0).release();
        songs.remove(0);
        Button NextSong = findViewById(R.id.NextSong);
        NextSong.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        final TextView result_display = findViewById(R.id.result_view);
        result_display.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
        songs.get(0).release();
        songs.remove(0);
        // CONGRATS
        final TextView result_display = findViewById(R.id.result_view);
        result_display.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        result_display.setText(getString(R.string.Congrats));
    }
```

Can you please help us reaching OnCompletion for the second time.

Comment: Can you post your set listener code? and are you registering OnErrorListner also? if mediaplayer throwing error then you can get there.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem with `songs.size`, Its look like you got 3 mediaplayer in arraylist and your `if else condtion` checking

`songs.size == 2
 songs.size == 3`

this is not correct, you should check

`songs.size() - 1` this will get 2nd song or mediaplayer

`songs.size() - 2` this will get 3rd song/mediaplayer

because arraylist start its index from 0.

and you are removing only 0th index element `songs.remove(0);` in every condition. I am not sure why, because according to your logic its should removed the song which is already completed like

`songs.remove(songs.size() - 1)
 songs.remove(songs.size() - 2)`

may be that also a issue. I don't know the whole logic so I can't comment.

Comment: Thanks, already tried it and didn´t work. Song number 1 plays as well as song number two, but when song number 2 ends it does not reach the onCompletion method and what is inside

Comment: there can be one more cause onCompletion not calling because before calling to onCompletion ```songs.remove``` method called. to check this case just comment all ```songs.remove``` code